# ng Ant Design : server pagination on top of table doesn't work

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

I want to put pagination on top of my table (I am using Ant Design for Angular), but the pagination is not working. But when I put it at the bottom it works fine.

My code is something like this:

```
<nz-table> .....</nz-table>
<nz-pagination> ... </nz-pagination>
```

this case works fine
but this case:

```
<nz-pagination> ... </nz-pagination>
<nz-table> .....</nz-table>
```

doesn't work!

(sorry for my weak English)

Answer (score 2):

[Check out the `nz-table` documentation](https://ng.ant.design/components/table/en).

Looks like the simpler way to implement pagination is just an attribute of the angular component you pass to the table, compared to a different component you need to include in the HTML:

```html
<nz-table
      #dynamicTable
      [nzData]="listOfData"
      [nzPaginationPosition]="position"
      [nzFrontPagination]="pagination"
      [nzShowPagination]="pagination"
    >
      <thead>
        <!-- ... -->
```

So, to make the pagination on top of the table, set the `[nzPaginationPosition]` attribute to `top`. [See the docs](https://ng.ant.design/components/table/en#nz-table)

These are the important attributes for pagination:

- `[nzFrontPagination]` - **BOOLEAN** - Whether paginate data in front-side should set to `false` if you want to paginate data in server-side or display all data in the table
- `[nzShowPagination]` - **BOOLEAN** - Whether show pagination component in the bottom of the table
- `[nzPaginationPosition]` - **BOOLEAN** - Specify the position of Pagination

So, in your case:

```html
<nz-table
      #dynamicTable
      [nzData]="listOfData"
      [nzPaginationPosition]="'top'"
      [nzFrontPagination]="false"
      [nzShowPagination]="true"
    >
      <thead>
        <!-- ... -->
```

Not to mention, you might want to also subscribe to the following events so you can respond to pagination (I think this is needed only for server-side pagination):

- `(nzPageIndexChange)` - **`EventEmitter<number>`** - pageIndex change callback
- `(nzPageSizeChange)` - **`EventEmitter<number>`** - pageSize change callback
- `(nzCurrentPageDataChange)` - **`EventEmitter<any[]>`** - Current pageData change callback

You technically can use the pagination as a separate component from your table. This means you need to connect the **`nz-table`** and the **`nz-pagination`** manually, by listening to pagination events to changing the table, and listen to table events to change the pagination. It sounds like in your situation it's not mandatory since you're trying to achieve something that the library supports (and the manual way will be much more complicated).

Comment: Can you give an example of manual process ? I have a case where i need to use nz-pagination with nz-table manually